# If I want use imagemagick in node.js I have to install imagemagick CLI tools?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I want use a imagemagick [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) to do some job about image, but beside install this module in my app, I have install the imagemagick into my computer?

the problem is my application is deploy on Paas platform, I don't think it provide the imagemagick CLI, so is there some other method I could choose?

Comment: If you add what PaaS platform, people may be able to give you a concrete solution instead of possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-imagemagick` actually *calls* the CLI tools (using `child_process`), hence the dependency.

As for an alternative, it really depends on what type of image manipulation you need (and also their dependencies as well, given that it has to run in a Paas platform). There's a nice list of graphics modules on [the Node wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-graphics).